Horror movie with aliens near a corn field
So all I can remember is that there were signs in the cornfield, I think it was with aliens but not sure. I remember that they had to barricade in a house and they were like dropped in morale and suddenly the aliens/monsters attacked the house and killed one of them and then left.
I think they were denying that there was something in the corn field at the start until they saw a cow mangled. I don't remember if some survived i think some of them survived. They were teens maybe.
It is not Signs, i think like a combination of Signs and Jeeper's Creepers. It isn't that old maybe 1990-2004.
If i remember correctly the ones who survived escape by car or with police, can`t remember how many 1-3 maybe. It was in english, american i think.
I think there was a scene that showed them how they were afraid to leave the house and there were days passing by without any attack.

Kinda sounds like it was based on the Kelly-Hopkinsville 'encounter'... That said, have you checked this list: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_films_featuring_extraterrestrials

Thank you so much, i found it in the list after some search. It`s called Silent Warnings(2003).

Could it be Alien Abduction: Incident in Lake County?
Here's the synopsis (from IMDB):

After a mysterious blackout, a son goes out to investigate and captures footage of actual aliens. When the aliens follow him and his brothers back to their home, all hell breaks loose.

The reason I think it might be the film you are referring to is because:
From here:

They find a UFO in a nearby field. As they watch from the treeline, two aliens exit the ship and use a ray-gun on a cow. Despite their attempt to remain hidden, the three men are spotted. One of the aliens raises its weapon and burns Brian's hand. They rush back to the house and try to convince their incredulous family to flee while there is still time. They see lights in the sky and a furtive figure outside a window, but the family refuses to believe the brothers' story until Tommy plays them the tape. Suddenly, a high-frequency screech incapacitates everyone but five-year-old Rose. When it stops, Kurt straps a flashlight to his shotgun and decides to get everyone in his truck and leave.

This fits with people denying the aliens and the cow angle. Then they make it to a house. Some people die, some people survive. It came out in 1998, which fits your time line. 
Do these people look familiar?


No, sorry, i just found it on a list that somebody gave to me. Its called Silent Warnings(2003). I think there were some wrong things that i said in the description because i didnt really remembered it or if i was confusing it with something else.

@AnimeCenter You might like to add that as an answer. It's allowed.

That someone sounds like a great guy. That said, the premise you gave, shakily, could have fit several films.

It seems the OP has abandoned the question after providing the answer.
The movie is Silent Warnings (2003)

After his cousin Joe (Stephen Baldwin) dies, Layne Vassimer (A. J. Buckley) and his girlfriend Macy (Callie De Fabry), along with their friends Stephen (David O'Donnell), Maurice (Ransford Doherty), Iris (Kim Onasch) and Katrina (Michelle Borth), decide to clean up Joe's house with the intention of selling it. When they see it for the first time, they discover the house completely covered in plates of iron armor.
The group also finds crop circles in the nearby cornfield. When Iris suddenly disappears, they realize something is really wrong. During a blackout, the house is attacked by aliens. The group figures out the aliens are allergic to iron, which is why Joe had covered the house in it to keep them out. They attempt to fight the aliens off, but the house is eventually blown up with Layne, Macy, and Katrina the only survivors.
In the end, they drive off, listening to the radio. They hear a news report stating that the blackout they experienced affects five western states and parts of Canada. They also hear that people everywhere are being attacked by "strange creatures."
Wikipedia

